# Monit - How to use different configurations for Day and Night time?

Tags: configuration, monit

What is the most convenient way to configure `monit` to act different in day and night hours?

The only thing I can figure out , is to use a `cron` job switch the `monitrc` file - let's say - at midnight, and restart the `Monit` service

Any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by act different, but redshift or night light are all that I know of that do that kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know redshift, it's good, and it's for adapt the screen light, anyway here I'm looking for a completely other thing, Monit is a tool to monitor system processes and to send alerts and evetually restart dead services. My question is if I can switch its configuration, in order to monitoring some stuff at day time, and some other stuff at night time